# How to find the point of a two dimensional array using the Point class in java.awt

Tags: java, arrays, coordinates

I have a two dimensional character array in a `Map` class

```
public class Map {
    private char[][] map;
}
```

which is 5 rows and columns in size (defined in a constructor). I also have a method in the same class

```
public Point findStart(){
   Point location=new Point();
      for ( int i=0; i<map.length; i++){
          if(map[i][i]=='s')
      System.out.println( "The starting position is in " + location.x + location.y );
      }
        return location;
    }
```

which iterates through the array to find the `"s"` character. Once it locates the character, I wish to make use of `java.awt`'s `Point` class to find the location of where the char 's' is located. How can I get the point to print out?

As MaxG has pointed out, my code is missing a for loop. The new method is

```
public Point findStart(){

        Point location=new Point();

        for ( int i=0; i<map.length; i++ ){
          for( int j=0; j<map[i].length; j++ )
           if(map[i][j]=='s')               
            location.getLocation();

      }

      System.out.println(location.x+","+location.y);
      return location;
    }
```

I still get 0,0 as coordinates though.

UPDATE: I think Christopher Chamberlain brings up a valid point. In the project I am reading from a .txt file and placing each character into the array.

```
//loads maps according to an integer parameter, which depends on what map the player is in (Map1, Map2, Map3, etc.)
    public void loadMap(int MapNum){

    //attemps to load .txt file
        try{
        String s="Map"+MapNum+".txt";
        File file=new File(s);
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(file);       

        while(sc.hasNextLine())
        {          
            for( int i=0; i<5; i++){

                char currentCharacter=sc.next().charAt(0);
                map[i][i]=currentCharacter;                           
            }  
        }      
        }
        catch(IOException exception){
            System.out.println(exception);
        }
    }
```

this method exists in the same class. I could be messing up somewhere while reading each character but I cannot figure out where?

Comment: First of all, you have a 2D array. To iterate through the array you have to use 2 for loops. With your code, you iterate only on one diagonal.

Comment: You are just creating a new `location` object using new Point() which will be (0,0) by default. Reference - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html#Point()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for somehting like this ?

```
public Point findStart() {
    Point location = new Point();
    for (int i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < map[i].length; j++) {
            if (map[i][j] == 's') {
                location.setLocation(i, j);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(location.x + "," + location.y);
    return location;
}
```

Comment: I have tried this but my coordinates are not getting updated.